# How to replace » "Right angle quotation mark" with MySQL

Tags: mysql, replace

i'm using that MySQL Query to format my wordpress post. It worked very well for characters like " and others, but not for "»". I made research to fix the problem, but i did not find a solution, also not here on stackoverflow.

When i execute this code nothing happend.

```
$query = "UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = REPLACE(post_content, '»<br />', '»\n\n')";
```

I tried this

```
$query = "UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = REPLACE(post_content, '\»<br />', '\»\n\n')";
```

and that

```
$query = "UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = REPLACE(post_content, '&raquo;<br />', '&raquo;\n\n')";
```

It is not working.

Comment: Can you use placeholder values? If so, this should be easy to do. Encoding it inside a double-quoted string is messing things up SQL statement-wise. Consider `REPLACE(content, ?, ?)` and then bind those two parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You must escape the `\n`

> ```
> CREATE TABLE wp_posts (post_content varchar(29))
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO wp_posts VALUES('a»<br />b')
> ```

> ```
> UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = REPLACE(post_content, '»<br />', '»\\n\\n')
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM wp_posts
> ```
>
> ```
> | post_content |
> | :----------- |
> | a»\n\nb     |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=3bd5cda477d6e724fe900a8dff23f754)*

Comment: I don't think a literal *backslash `n`* is the desired outcome here.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, your solution did not work for me. I will try $conn->set_charset("utf8"); Maybe that helps

Comment: yes if you have utf8 then [utf8 all the way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through) through is the only way

Comment: This is working $query = "UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = REPLACE(post_content, '»<br />', '»\n\n')"; when i set mysqli_set_charset($conn,"utf8");

Comment: leave the double \ as you they don't hurt